# mongo db query check that no other document with matched values exist

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to create a query with which I can check if a document has related documents, e.g. I have a document

```
{
name:"test1", 
status:"CREATED"
date:"2018-12-12"
user:"foo"
}
```

and i want to retreive all documents where the user has no document with `status:"OPEN"`

I had the idea to project a field with the number of documents which are open for the user & day and filter for 0, but I don't know how I could do that.

So when i have the following documents:

[image]

it should only return foo2 and foo4 because foo, foo3 and foo5 already have documents with `status:"OPEN"`

Comment: Java or Javascript? They are quite different, and rarely interchangeable

Comment: I am working with java, but I run the query on the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below code to get all the documents for users for whom no 'OPEN' status exists:

```
db.collection.find({
  user: {
    $nin: db.collection.find({status: 'OPEN'}).map((row) => row.user)
  }
});
```

- $nin: to specify and exclusion list.
- .map((row) => row.user): to convert array of filtered documents to array of just the string containing user ids.

Comment: thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic:

1.First query all the doc with status OPEN

2.Now you have a sets of data with OPEN only doc

4.Now create a query where you pass all the userId of this set in query and fetch those values from collection which have userId not equal to the passed ones

Example:

```
db.collectionName.find({status:'OPEN'});// set1


db.collectionName.find({userId:{$not : 'userid1'}},{userId:{$not : 'userid2'}},....);
```

This is not good code but this is all you can do now or add some other fields in db to do it more effectively

Comment: I want to find all documents which have no other documents for the useId. so i want only the documents where no other document with user foo and status OPEN exists

Comment: If you want only status : 'CREATED' and userId: 'foo2' you can do this: db.collectionName.find({status:'CREATED',userId:'foo2'});

Comment: yeah, I know, but I want to query that for all users, not for single ones.

Comment: Tell me this on which fields you want to query your database mention them

Comment: I want to find all documents for which no other document exists which has the same `userId` and `status: "OPEN"`

Comment: db.collectionName.find({status:'CREATED',userId:'foo2'}); this query give you all the documents with userId foo2 and status CREATED not OPEN.It won't give any document with userId foo2 and status OPEN

Comment: I updated the question again. I dont want to pass specific values, i want to query all documents and retreive the ones which match my criteria